# How to call a class for another in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop

I create a Prestashop 1.7 module. For example mymodule.php. In this module I have __construct and

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/mymodule_class.php');
```

In folder classes (in my own module) I create a file, mymodule_class.php

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class mymodule_class{

    protected static $module = false;

    public function test(){
        return 'test';
    }
 }
```

In another module I want to call 'test' function:

```
print_r(mymodule_class::test)
```

or

```
$mymodule_class = new mymodule_class();
print_r (mymodule_class->test());
```

But I have error:

> Attempted to load class "mymodule_class" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement?

I don't understand this message. In my option everything should be ok. thanks for help.

Comment: You need put more code of the `mymodule.php` to see what you did exactly.

Answer (score 1):

In the file of other module where you are calling function of class mymodule_class
Add
`include_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'yourmodulename/classes/mymodule_class.php';`

Please add this line in your top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In your another module you can call the file if the class doesn't exists with a code like this :

```
<?php

     $module_class_filename = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'mymodule/mymoduleclass.php';         

     if (class_exists('mymoduleclass') || file_exists($module_class_filename)) {
        // You can call the object
        $mymodule = new mymoduleclass();
     } else {
        // You cannot
     }
 ?>
```

Please remember to add a constructor and try to respect validator generator format for Modules (https://validator.prestashop.com/generator) to make it compliant with Prestashop's development standards.

Answer (score 0):

Call a method:

```
$myModule = Module::getInstance('MyModule');
$myModule->myMethod();
```

Call a static method:

```
MyModule::myStaticMethod();
```